# replace table layout with DIVs

Tags: html, css

I am new to DIV tags with CSS layout. I have the following layout in Tables and trying to replace with DIVs. We are using DIV tags in our application. So I do not want interfere with existing layout.  I appreciate any input.

```
<table style="width:100%;" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 80%; " colspan="4"></td><td rowspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%; "></td><td style="width: 20%; "></td><td style="width: 20%; "></td><td style="width: 20%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 40%; " colspan="2"></td><td style="width: 40%; " colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are using the div/table for. It could well be that a table would be perfect for the content. However, it is hard to tell at present.

Comment: based off the information given, I would suggest looking into a framework such as [Bootstrap Grids](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/). although @LeeTaylor makes a good point. without more information we have no clue what would be better suited for your projects purposes.

Comment: If I understand your question, display="table"  obviate your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already mentioned you should probably use some framework, such as ***Bootstrap*** for example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

However here is a small ***fiddle example*** of "table" only with "DIV tags": https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/q3f21Lnk/

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="first">
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="one">
            <div class="one-fourth"></div>
            <div class="one-fourth"></div>
            <div class="one-fourth"></div>
            <div class="one-fourth"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">
            <div class="one-half"></div>
            <div class="one-half"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

[image]